# Filter query if security access is granted in doctrine / Delete entities from knp paginator

Tags: security, symfony, doctrine-orm, pagination, knppaginator

I'm using symfony2, doctrine, knp paginator and security voters.
In my application each user have some children. I should display a list of child that belong to current user (defined by current logged user).

So I created a security voter which grants user access only to its own child. It perfectly works in that cases:

```
if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('view', $child))
```

or

```
{% for entity in pagination if app.security.isGranted('view', child) %}
```

As you can imagine, paginator doesn't work correctly because I simply don't show children at the current page. Consequently my paginator becomes a trash.

I see two possible solutions:

- filter entities at stage of query. Question is how can I use **isGranted** in doctrine querybuilder?
- Do something with paginator, eliminating properly unwanted children

I realize that I could modify my query adding something like **->andWhere('c.parent == :user')** but this listig facility is very general and is used to list dozens of different relation like *user-child*, *user-group-town-orders*, *user-post-tags*, *user-films*.

Comment: I have a solution. I added special method to my voters which take a QueryBuiler object and modify it with respect to current logged user. In controller I get all voters, take appropriate and pass query to them. For more details leave a comment

Comment: I'm interested in how you did this!